# Command to find largest file in hadoop directory

Tags: bash, hadoop, directory, find, large-files

I am trying to find the largest file in a given directory on a hadoop filesystem. I found this link: http://www.tecmint.com/find-top-large-directories-and-files-sizes-in-linux/, which showed the following command for finding the largest file:

```
find /home/tecmint/Downloads/ -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 5
```

But when I ran

```
hadoop fs -find [hadoop location] -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 5
```

I got `find: Unexpected argument: -type`.

I also ran `hadoop fs -du -a | sort -n | head -n 1` but the result I was getting was not the largest file in the directory. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried `hadoop fs -ls -S |head -1` ? I don't use hadoop and i'm not sure if -S exists for ls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux you can run the following command to find the largest file in Desktop directory, remove the -r argument of sort if you want to find the file with smallest size!

```
du ~/Desktop/* | sort -n -r | head -n 1
```

For HDFS you can try the following command

```
hadoop fs -du <Path-in-HDFS> | sort -n -r | head -n 1
```